# Check is category parent or not from its ID

Tags: categories, functions

question is simple (i don't know is aswer too ;)
I just want to check that, does a category has child (or is ancestor) from its cat-id with a function.
Eg.
`function check_category ($catid){
............
...//true if is ancestor, false if not
return $result;
}`


Note: I can only pass cat-id parameter for function because i need to use it in functions.php
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function category_has_parent($catid){
    $category = get_category($catid);
    if ($category->category_parent > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
if (category_has_parent('22')){
   //true there is a parent category
}else{
   //false this category has no parent
}
```

### Update:

to check the other way around (if a category has children) you can use get_categories

```
$children = get_categories(array('child_of' => id,'hide_empty' => 0));
if (count($children) > 1){
    //has childern
}else{
    //no children
}
```

Comment: First snippet can be probably streamlined to `return $category->category_parent`.

Comment: @Bainternet, I'am sory but i asked question incorrect. I want to learn that is this category ($catid) endmost? I mean, if a category has no child then it is endmost.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: So you need the opposite of that, instead of checking if it has a parent you want to check if it has child categories?

Comment: @Bainternet, yes and i've sold my problem with: $catlist = wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&hide_empty=0&title_li=&child_of='.$categoryid);
if (($catlist)!='<li>No categories</li>')

Comment: @Alper , check the answer again, I've added a much nicer way to do it.

Comment: @Bainternet, woaw.. its perfect (and very clever idea), thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents

```
// returns true or false    
function check_category( $cat_id ){
    $parent = '';
    $parent = get_category_parents( $cat_id );
    return empty($parent);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, by mechanics `get_category_parents()` its output will always have at least category itself.

Comment: I'am sory but i asked question incorrect. I want to learn that is this category ($catid) endmost? I mean, if a category has no child then it is endmost.. Thanks in advance...